# Sublime text 2 sftp, unable to upload folder on mac

Tags: macos, sftp, sublimetext2

I have installed the sublime text 2 on my mac,installed package control and sftp package, add the folder to project, mapped it to remote. And now i've got the problem while trying to upload wordpress folder.

```
2012-09-06 23:33:51
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sftp/threads.py", line 16, in run_with_except_hook
  File "./sftp/threads.py", line 101, in handler
  File "./sftp/commands.py", line 264, in run
  File "./sftp/commands.py", line 403, in do_operation
  File "./sftp/file_transfer.py", line 25, in handler
  File "./sftp/sftp_transport.py", line 565, in put
  File "./sftp/file_transfer.py", line 330, in handle_put_dirs
  File "./sftp/sftp_transport.py", line 284, in cd
NotFoundError: Folder not found
```

my stfp config

```
"type": "sftp",

"save_before_upload": true,
"upload_on_save": true,
"sync_down_on_open": false,
"sync_skip_deletes": false,
"confirm_downloads": false,
"confirm_sync": true,
"confirm_overwrite_newer": true,

"host": "xxx.nazwa.pl",
"user": "xxx",
"password": "xxx",
//"port": "22",

"remote_path": "/xxx/",
```

I've done the same on windows and it worked just fine. Any ideas whats wrong?